# Bump Gradle version without bumping Android Gradle Plugin version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been staying on the beta channel of Android Gradle Plugin for a while now. Periodically an AGP update will also bump the Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

When this happens is AGP bumping Gradle to the minimum supported version. Or is this the "desired" version that AGP wants to work with?

What happens if I manually bump Gradle past this? For example, right now I'm on AGP 3.4beta5, which has set Gradle to 5.1.1.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

What happens if I manually set the version to 5.3 or 5.4? https://gradle.org/releases/ Is this generally a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-4-0. This link suggests that we can use 'Gradle 5.1.1 or higher'.

Comment: Thanks. However I'm looking to differentiate between "can use" and "should use".